# Codeigniter (CSRF) jQuery ajax problem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I’ve got a issue here, i keep getting a error when i try to post something with ajax (POST). I know it is the CSRF that gives me these problems and I’ve been tried back and forth trying to find a solution. However, i hope somebody here can help me out!

This is the error i keep getting (from google chrome inspector),

****Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost/woho/ajax/images".****

PHP (Controller)

```
class Ajax extends CI_Controller {

    function images() {

        echo 'Hello World';

    }

}
```

Javascript

```
var ID = $(".imageWrap:last").attr("id");
var baseurl = "http://localhost/woho/";
var doScroll = 1;
var cct = $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name');

if (location.href == baseurl) {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('body').height() / 2) {
            if(doScroll == 1) {                   
                $.post(baseurl + 'ajax/images',{'id' : ID, 'csrf_token_name': cct}, function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $("#wrapper_content").append(data);
                    ID++;
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

my CCT var from javascript gives me the correct token or "hash" but when the javascript sends the ajax request codeigniter returns an error like,

> An Error Was Encountered  The action you have requested is
>   not allowed.

How can i fix this? do i need to validate the CSRF Token or something in my controller?

I'm using Codeigniter 2.0.3

Comment: by the way, in 2.0.3 there is no such thing as `$this->security->get_csrf_token_name();` Not sure where @Alfonso Rubalcava got that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try (javascript):

```
var ID = $(".imageWrap:last").attr("id");
var baseurl = "http://localhost/woho/";
var doScroll = 1;
var cct = $.cookie("<?php echo $this->config->item("csrf_cookie_name"); ?>");

if (location.href == baseurl) {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('body').height() / 2) {
            if(doScroll == 1) {                   
                $.post(baseurl + 'ajax/images',{'id':ID,'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': cct}, function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $("#wrapper_content").append(data);
                    ID++;
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: OMFG, Ofc i need to use the actual name, and not the var. Haha, man, thanks! Tunnel vision next?

Answer (score 3):

check value of your `$config['csrf_token_name']` in /application/config/config.php as default is setted as **csrf_test_name** not **csrf_token_name**.

This decision if you not want to use PHP code in Javascript.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'some_url',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {csrf_test_name: $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name')}
});
```

This code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `form_open("/some",'id="some_form"')` and `form_close()` , CI create a hidden input that keep the csrf_token_name and it value.

so , in your AJAX request , you can get the form by serialize it and send form !

For example:

```
<script>
var _form = $("#some_form").serializeArray();
$.ajax({
    data: _form,
    type: 'post',
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>some',
    async: true,
    success: function(output){
        alert(output);
    },
    complete: function(output){},
    fail: function(err){}
});
</script>
```

The CSRF always was my problem and by this method, it solved!!

Answer (score 0):

it may be late but i found this perfect solution sort of hack but should work

```
if (isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) 
{
    if(stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'/mypage') === FALSE)
    {
        $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
    } 
} 
else 
{
    $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
}
```

// in config.php file ci 2.*

found solution from [this post](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/182631/)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem but now I have fixed this problem.

First of all, I have created csrf_token in header.php for every pages like below code

```
$csrf = array(
                'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
                'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
        );

<script type="text/javascript">
    var cct = "<?php echo $csrf ['hash']; ?>";
  </script>
```

After that, when we are sending particular value through ajax then we will have to sent csrf token like below code

```
$.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo APPPATHS.'staff_leave/leaveapproval/getAppliedLeaveDetails'; ?>",
    data:{id:id,status:status,'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': cct},
    method:"post",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(response)
    {
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

I hope this code will help you because this is working for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just follow this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url  : 'Your URL',
    data : {
        id: id,
        '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
    },
    datatype: 'json',
    success : function(data){}
});
```

Comment: I think this is the same answer as the other ones, including the accepted.