# CodeIgniter, Ajax call does not get into Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery, codeigniter-2

After looking at a solution on [ci-ajax-csrf-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348383/codeigniter-ajax-csrf-problem) I added the following line into the script and it works fine.

```
var post_data = {
    '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
}
```

inserted into

```
$.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url()."ajax/test";?>',
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: post_data,
```

Thank you for the help everyone :)

I am new to Ajax/Jquery and was following a guide on Ajax for CodeIgniter from [jorge torres](http://www.jotorres.com/2012/01/using-jquery-and-ajax-with-codeigniter/) to implement a simple ajax call on my website and ran into problems.

I created a Controller Ajax and this is the code snippet.

```
class Ajax extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function test() {
        $output_string = 'This is a test';  
        echo json_encode($output_string);
    }

    public function test2(){
        $this->load->view('test.php');
    }
}
```

And this is the view for that controller, its identical to the one from the tutorial except I added loaded the url helper $this->load->helper('url'); on the first line

Here is the snippet for the script code.

The #getdata is a button type and #result_table is a div

```
$('#getdata').click(function(){
$.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url().'ajax/test';?>',
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output_string){
                $('#result_table').append(output_string);
            } // End of success function of ajax form
        }); // End of ajax call
});
```

I can successfully access *localhost.com/codeigniter/ajax/test2* but when I clicked the button, nothing happen.

I tried looking at the page source info and the url is correct

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/codeigniter/ajax/test',
        type:'POST'
        ....
```

Accessing *localhost/codeigniter/ajax/test* directly is also possible and it display the output message.

I am using CodeIgniter 2.1.3 and my localhost is running on XAMPP 1.7.3

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: check your browser console for any erros

Comment: have you wrapped the jquery code in $(document).ready(function() { ... }); ..?

Comment: I am recommending  you to install firebug or some kind of developer tools.Check the console for the errors.

Comment: Plz test with it firebug tools. See what happen when you click in button.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @arun-p-johny , I tried looking at the browser console and it returns a 500 Internal Server Error with an error message "The action you require is not allowed".

Comment: I have also added the $(document).ready(function) as @Sudhir suggested but still giving the same error.

Comment: May be a CSRF token issue then, check my last edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at a solution on [ci-ajax-csrf-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348383/codeigniter-ajax-csrf-problem) I added the following line into the script and it works fine.

```
var post_data = {
    '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
}
```

inserted into

```
$.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url()."ajax/test";?>',
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: post_data,
```

Thank you for the help everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with your ajax call . Should be like this I think :

```
$(document).ready (function () { 
   $('#getdata').click(function(){
     $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url()."ajax/test";?>',
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output_string){
                $('#result_table').append(output_string);
            } // End of success function of ajax form
        }); // End of ajax call
    });
});
```

If the firebug console says that The action you require is not allowed, then it may be a CSRF token issue, turn it off in the codeigniter config.

Add this in config file.

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes It was caused by CSRF being enabled, I have found a solution and it works fine :) Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

Did your .click() event handler works as expected?

```
$('#getdata').click(function(){
 alert('clicked');
 ........
```

if no, try to wrapped the jquery code `in $(document).ready(function() { ... });` as @Sudhir suggested:

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
      $('#getdata').click(function(){
      alert('clicked');
      ........

});
```

if yes, in case you don't know it yet, there's a tool called [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to check your AJAX request. 
I thinks there's no problem with your AJAX url.
So far, this is my answer. Hope this helps too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I checked the console using firebug and it returns a 500 Internal Server Error with a message of "The action you have requested is not allowed."

Answer (score 0):

Do you have output compression enabled(gzip) in your config.php? If you compress your output it will fail when you use echo and return the 500 server errors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I checked the config and its disabled

Comment: Sorry just remembered another cause was csrf. Try turning it off to test. If it works check here for the workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351849/codeigniter-csrf-jquery-ajax-problem

Comment: As the solution link you gave is quite different, I used a solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348383/codeigniter-ajax-csrf-problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$(document).ready (function () { 
   $('#getdata').click(function(){
     $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/test',
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output_string){
                $('#result_table').append(output_string);
            } // End of success function of ajax form
        }); // End of ajax call
    });
});
```

as apposed to `<?php base_url; ?>`

Have you entered your site url into the CI config?