# error 501 method no implemented on jquery codeigniter

Tags: php, android, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i have a problem when i post a form using jquery and codeigniter the response showing error 501 method no implemented. i'm get this error when using smartphone browser like android.this is my code :

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var obj=$('#recoveryForm');
        obj.find(':submit').removeClass('disabled');
        obj.validate({
        submitHandler: function() {
             $.ajax({
                 cache:false,
                 dataType:'json',
                 url: "<?=base_url();?>reseller/changePassword",
                 type: "POST",
                 data: obj.serialize(),
                 beforeSend:function(){
                     obj.find(':submit').button('loading');
                 },
                 success:function(data){
                     if(data.status=='false'){
                          $('#alert').html('<div class="alert alert-danger center">'+data.noty+'</div>');
                          obj.find(':submit').button('reset');
                     }else{
                         $('#alert').html('<div class="alert alert-success center">'+data.noty+'<br><br><a href="<?=base_url();?>" class="btn btn-pink">Back to Home</a></div>');
                         obj.fadeOut('slow',function(){obj.remove()});
                     }
                 },
                  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                     $('#alert').html('<div class="alert alert-danger center">'+xhr.status+' '+ thrownError+'</div>');
                     obj.find(':submit').button('reset');
                  }
              });
            }
        });
    });
```

And this my php code

```
    public function changePasswordR(){

    if($this->check_login()){
        $data=$this->input->post(null,true);
        if(!empty($data['password']) || !empty($data['newpassword']) || !empty($data['konfirmpassword'])){
            $user=$this->reseller_data();
            $row=$this->madmin->read(__CLASS__,'where email= "'.$user['email'].'"');
            if(!empty($row)){
                if($this->salt($data['password'])==$row[0]->password){
                    if($this->madmin->update(__CLASS__,'email',$row[0]->email,array('password'=>$this->salt($data['newpassword'])))){
                        //noty
                        $this->madmin->create('notification',array('id'=>null,'time'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),'msg'=>$row[0]->nama.' mengubah passwordnya'));
                        die(json_encode(array('status'=>'true','noty'=>'<script type="text/javascript">alert("Selamat '.$row[0]->nama.', password anda berhasil diubah. Silahkan melakukan login ulang menggunakan password baru anda.");window.location.href = "'.base_url().'logout";</script>')));
                    }else{
                        die(json_encode(array('status'=>'false','noty'=>'Gagal mengubah password, silahkan coba beberapa saat lagi.')));
                    }
                }else{
                    die(json_encode(array('status'=>'false','noty'=>'Password lama salah.')));
                }
            }else{
                die(json_encode(array('status'=>'false','noty'=>'Akun tidak ditemukan.')));
            }
        }else{
            die(json_encode(array('status'=>'false','noty'=>'Data tidak lengkap.')));
        }
    }else{
        die(json_encode(array('status'=>'false','noty'=>'Login kembali untuk melanjutkan.')));
    }
}

enter code here
```

Please help me !

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i don't know why but i add this code

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

and it's work

Comment: You should add some text explaining what this answer does and why it provides a solution to the specific problem. Code dumps are rarely ever of use to other people.

Answer (score 1):

If You Enabled The CSRF Checking on your project, you should send the csrf_token_name to CI.
so , you should use form_open("/some_url",'') And form_close() in your HTML codes and then Serialize the form and send to server.

```
var _form = $("#some_form").serializeArray();
```

check this:
[Codeigniter (CSRF) jQuery ajax problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351849/codeigniter-csrf-jquery-ajax-problem/26742387#26742387)

Answer (score 0):

change this line in view

```
url: "<?=base_url();?>reseller/changePassword",
```

to

```
url: "<?php echo base_url('reseller/changePassword');?>",
```

add below line to controller method

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

and use echo instead of die

```
echo json_encode(array(....));
```